# How do I connect an AppVM running the CLI to a separate AppVM running monerod in Qubes?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod

I have monerod running on an AppVM in Qubes and want to run the CLI in a separate AppVM to minimize the exposure to my wallet files.  First, is there any downside to this approach? Second, can someone provide a walk through for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup your firewall to allow connections between the two VMs.

Run this on startup (some script linked from /rw/config/rc.local):

`/usr/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp --dport 18081 -m conntrack --ctstate new -j ACCEPT`

This allows incoming RPC calls.

In the firewall VM, allow the two VMs to talk to each other (again, from /rw/config/rc.local):

`/usr/bin/iptables -I FORWARD 2 -s a.b.c.d -d e.f.g.h -j ACCEPT`

`/usr/bin/iptables -I FORWARD 2 -s e.f.g.h -d a.b.c.d -j ACCEPT`

Rule numbers kinda arbitrary here, especially for your setup.